# How to create appbar button PathIcon from a svg image with multiple paths?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

Am creating window 8.1 application application bar button in a view.

Am trying to create appbar button image from this svg image paths.

```
 <AppBarButton  AutomationProperties.Name="Label" RequestedTheme="Default"  Label="print Label"  Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="print label">
         <AppBarButton.Icon>
              <PathIcon Data="M13.5,14.25v-5h13v5h-2v-2.5h13v2.5H13.5z"/>
         </AppBarButton.Icon>
 </AppBarButton>
```

Below is `svg image` in `Text format`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 40 40" enable-background="new 0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<g>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M26.508,14.365h-0.12l-13.14-0.021c-0.581,0-1.051-0.476-1.049-1.056c0-0.58,0.469-1.052,1.05-1.052
        l13.141,0.008c0.582,0,1.053,0.482,1.053,1.062c-0.002,0.578-0.473,1.06-1.053,1.06"/>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M21.198,11.71h0.066l-2.89-0.108c-0.389-0.002-0.702-0.364-0.7-0.752s0.274-0.72,0.702-0.724l2.891-0.005
        c0.389,0.004,0.701,0.41,0.699,0.799c-0.001,0.385-0.312,0.79-0.699,0.79"/>
    <g>
        <g>
            <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M26.39,15.34h-13.03l0.083,1.465c0,0.042-0.009,0.08-0.007,0.122l0.569,11.524
                c0.043,0.871,0.793,1.587,1.67,1.587h8.399c0.875,0,1.624-0.716,1.67-1.587l0.568-11.524c0.002-0.042-0.005-0.08-0.007-0.122
                L26.39,15.34z M16.398,28.466c0,0-0.017,0.001-0.024,0.001c-0.383,0-0.699-0.301-0.713-0.686l-0.371-9.987
                c-0.016-0.391,0.292-0.724,0.685-0.738c0.381-0.005,0.725,0.294,0.74,0.688l0.372,9.982
                C17.101,28.12,16.795,28.451,16.398,28.466z M20.513,27.754c0,0.39-0.312,0.701-0.699,0.701
                c-0.389-0.001-0.701-0.313-0.701-0.701l0.014-9.985c0-0.387,0.312-0.7,0.7-0.7h0.002c0.385,0.001,0.7,0.314,0.7,0.7
                L20.513,27.754z M23.968,27.782c-0.015,0.384-0.328,0.685-0.712,0.685c-0.009,0-0.016-0.001-0.028-0.001
                c-0.392-0.015-0.7-0.349-0.685-0.74l0.396-9.981c0.015-0.395,0.34-0.703,0.74-0.688c0.391,0.017,0.7,0.349,0.684,0.74
                L23.968,27.782z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
 </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

I created PathIcon Image if there is `only one path data` in the svg image.
 But how to handle the above case where they used `more than one path` for creating it.
  If any idea please..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the response from msdn forum.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b0506eca-27b2-409a-b624-66c98274bcec/how-to-create-appbar-button-pathicon-from-a-svg-image-with-multiple-paths?forum=winappswithcsharp

Thanks [Matt Small](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/matt%20small/?ws=usercard-mini) for the information!